# Is is possible to print a variable name from list

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, printing

Let's say we have a list of variables and we want to print the variables names + values in python but without using a dictionary cause the values will be added later on and we don't want to convert from dict to list.

```
A, B, C, D ,E, F = 10, 20, 15, 50, 16
Census = [A,B,C,D,E,F]
```

Is it possible to iterate through a list and print out the variables names beside the values and late sum?

Comment: I don't believe there is. The moment you reference `A`, you get back its value. You should probably just use a dictionary.